# Does Firebase Cloud Messaging support Http V1 and Http at same time?

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Currently, Our system is using Legacy server key to send notification to FCM.
According to FCM document, suggest to use HTTP V1.
The question is, after we generated HTTP V1 account, Can we still use the legacy server key?

Answer (score 0):

There are some instances where Internal Server Error occurs upon still using the Legacy server key, it is recommended to [migrate](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/auth-server#migrate-legacy-server-keys) into using the newer server keys instead.